# how to count number values' frequency using python pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to count the frequency of number values of csv data in my computer.
I tried this code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("C:/address.csv")
df=pd.DataFrame(data==data)
df.apply(pd.value_counts)
```

I tried to use 'value_counts' but I don't know how to apply it.

Result that I want is
in a row of "number(from 1 to 50): n times"

I hope that I want to solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry are you after `df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts)`?

Answer (score 1):

Are you already trying:

```
df['column name'].value_counts()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `cumcount()` function.

```
df['number_count'] = df.groupby('col_of_interest').cumcount()
```

Answer (score 0):

groupby together with count does not give the frequency of unique values.

Try using size, with group, to get unique values with their frequencies

```
Dataframe.groupby('column_name').size()
```

For faster computation and if your dataframe has values with same type, 
You can use;

```
index, counts = np.unique(df.values,return_counts=True)
```

If your values are all integers, then try using np.bincount()